# Qt - Return value when signal is emitted?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I get a function to return a value only when a signal is emitted?

The FileDownloader class emits a 'downloaded()' signal when download is complete. I want to return the downloaded data after the downloaded() signal is emitted.

```
QImage ImgDownloader::downloadIMG(QUrl url){
    fd = new FileDownloader(url, this);
    //????
    return QImage::fromData(fd->downloadedData());
}
```

Edit: To clarify things, downloadIMG() function is not a slot or signal.

FileDownloader contains the slots and signals as follows from (https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL)

```
class FileDownloader : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
  explicit FileDownloader(QUrl imageUrl, QObject *parent = 0);
  virtual ~FileDownloader();
  QByteArray downloadedData() const;

 signals:
  void downloaded();

 private slots:
  void fileDownloaded(QNetworkReply* pReply);

 private:
  QNetworkAccessManager m_WebCtrl;
  QByteArray m_DownloadedData;
};
```

What I want to achieve is to create a function that return a QImage from a QUrl [QImage func(QUrl)]. However I want to make sure that the data has been downloaded before returning the value. (utilising the downloaded() signal?)

Comment: Return it where?

Comment: I want the function to return a QImage from the FileDownloader

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense if `downloadIMG` is a slot. You have to use emit to send the data to a place where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be in a confusion. Even though signals in Qt can indeed return values, this is rarely used, if ever. Namely because it doesn't make a lot of sense.

What you probably want to do is not return but emit the image with a signal, this way you can connect it to a function that will receive the image and do something with it.

In that event, you want the signal to be declared as:

```
void downloaded(QImage img);
```

And emitted via:

```
emit downloaded(Image::fromData(fd->downloadedData()));
```

or just:

```
downloaded(Image::fromData(fd->downloadedData()));
```

as `emit` is just decoration for the sake of readability that doesn't do anything.

> What I want to achieve is to create a function that return a QImage
>   from a QUrl [QImage func(QUrl)]. However I want to make sure that the
>   data has been downloaded before returning the value.

The only way this can happen is if you use a blocking API, but it is not recommended to do that in the main/GUI thread, as your application will appear to be non-responsive to the OS. You will have to do it in another thread and pass the end result to the main thread if you want to use the image in the GUI. At any rate, you will still have to use the above signal declaration that emits to image in order to get it there. When you make the connection to the main thread, Qt will detect that the two objects run in different threads and use a queued connection for you.

Or you can do a non-blocking implementation that runs periodically in the main thread without blocking it.

But the only way to get from an URL to an image in one function is to block the function with the data download.

Comment: Emit meant to be used on signal, not slot. it kinda work only with synchronous call of slot.. such cannot be called safely in asynchronous way, I suppose. if it's unknown when result should appear, one have to use something like a `future` object

Comment: @Swift - the OP is quite clear on the subject: `emits a 'downloaded()' signal`. Dunno where you got the idea of slots...

Comment: @gxexx, `QNetworkReply` already has `finished` signal emitted when the reply has finished processing.

Answer (score -1):

`emit` meant to be used on signal, not slot. It is true that usually it is  just an empty macro and signal is actual method called by your emitting code.  Signal may call slot directly or it may use indirect, asynchronous call, when the slot belongs to other thread.

Such slot as you plan cannot be called safely in asynchronous way. You can pass arguments by reference to slot through custom signal, but IF that's called asynchronously you must have synchronization in place. One of ways to do so is to use a future class: `QFuture` or `std::future` (`QFuture` in your case probably more preferable). That way the caller thread will know when callee  had finished downloading. Just return the status of download (error code or lack thereof) as result.

Your slot might be implemented in same thread as caller, but process would be a separate QThread, which will be run from slot and would update the status.